# Storing strings in list with loop, then printing the list

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

My goal is to ask the user to enter a bunch of strings in a loop, and when they enter "stop", the loop breaks and prints all those strings with a comma at the end of each word. For example, if the user enters "first", "second", "third", and "fourth", then the program would print the following:

first, second, third, fourth

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i;
    String s;
    String[] listOfStrings = new String[1000];
    String last = "";
    System.out.println("Please enter some Strings: ");
    for (i = 1; i>0; i++) {
        listOfStrings[i] = kb.next();
        last = listOfStrings[i] + ",";
        if (listOfStrings[i].equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {

            break;
        }
    }
        System.out.print(last);
```

There is a problem because it always just winds up printing the last word and nothing else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to your code you are printing the last one. You will need to print each String in listOfStrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an `ArrayList`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String s = sc.next();
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
        break;
    } else {
        list.add(s);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i) + ",");
}
```

If you want everything in one line, you can do this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = "";

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String s = sc.next();
    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
        break;
    } else {
        line += s + ", ";
    }
}

System.out.println(line.substring(0, line.length()-2));
```

Comment: I'm using NetBeans 8.1 and for some reason "List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();" doesn't work.

Comment: You need to import them into the project, you can try autofixing in Netbeans, if I remember correctly netbeans shows red exclamation on error line, you can hover your mouse over it and then click auto resolve

Comment: You need to import it: `import java.util.*;`